# Catch exception thrown from Custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1, jsonconverter

I am looking for a way to catch an exception thrown from a custome Newtonsoft's `JsonConverter`.

I created the following custom converter. `JsonConverter` attribute in `Config` class uses it. `Config` class is used to post a config object and used for Web API POST method (I'm using .NET Core 3.1).

The converter works fine but when an exception is thrown, the middleware that handles exceptions does not catch it. For instance, I expected that the middleware would catch `MissingConfigTypeException` when `type` is null in the HTTP request body, but the `Func` in `appBuilder.Run()` never gets called. Any exceptions thrown from the converter are never caught by the middleware.
Because the exception is not processed by the middleware, the API method returns http status code `500` with no HTTP response body. I want to return `400` with my custom error message.

My goals are (I need to achieve both):

- Return http `400` error instead of `500` and
- Return my custom error in HTTP response body (`Error` object. See the middleware below)

I wonder if there is a way to catch an exception somehow (using the middleware or otherwise) or modify HTTP response body (I'll have to be able to identify that a particular error occurred so I can modify the response body only when the error occurs)

Note: I don't want to use `ModelState` in my controller action method (don't want to add some sort of error checking code for each method).

**Update**
The middleware can catch exceptions thrown from controller action methods.

My custom converter:

```
public class ConfigJsonConverter :  JsonConverter 
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (jObject == null) throw new InvalidConfigException();

        var type = jObject["type"] ?? jObject["Type"];
        if (type == null) throw new MissingConfigTypeException();

        var target = CreateConfig(jObject);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }


    private static Config CreateConfig(JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = (string)jObject.GetValue("type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (Enum.TryParse<ConfigType>(type, true, out var configType))
        {
            switch (configType)
            {
                case ConfigType.TypeA:
                    return new ConfigA();
                case ConfigType.TypeB:
                    return new ConfigB();
            }
        }

        throw new UnsupportedConfigTypeException(type, jObject);
    }
```

Config class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConfigJsonConverter))]
public abstract class Config {...}

public class ConfigA : Config {...}
```

The middleware:

```
// This is called in startup.cs
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    return application.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder => appBuilder.Run(async context =>
    {
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

        Error error;
        switch (exception)
        {
            case InvalidConfigException typedException:
                error = new Error
                {
                    Code = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Message = typedException.Message
                };
                break;

            case MissingConfigTypeException typedException:
                error = new Error
                {
                    Code = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Message = typedException.Message
                };
                break;
            .....
        }

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = error.Code;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }));
}
```

**Update:**
Startup.cs

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    if (EnableHttps)
        app.UseHsts();
    ...

    app
        .UseForwardedHeaders()
        .UsePathBase(appConfig.BasePath);

    if (EnableHttps)
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app
        .UseRouting()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        })
        .UseCustomExceptionHandler(logger);
```

Comment: Please add  `Configure` part of your startup class.

Comment: Guru Stron I have added startup.cs. I've mentioned this in the post but the middleware can catch exceptions thrown from the controller action methods. So, it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your `UseCustomExceptionHandler` before setting up endpoints and routing:

```
app
    .UseCustomExceptionHandler(logger)
    .UseRouting()
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Also based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#developer-exception-page) exception handling usually is set up one of the first in pipeline, even before `app.UseHsts()`.